# Can we write a portable include guard that doesn’t use the preprocessor in C++?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

Can we write a portable include guard that doesn’t use the preprocessor in C++? If so how could that be done?

Comment: Really, the whole issue is with the preprocessor, since it completely relates to #include -- which is a preprocessor directive.

Comment: How could you prevent multiple includes *after* the preprocessor did its job ?

Comment: The problem lies with the #include directive, not the include guards.

Comment: I think we can do it at compile time using templates .. But I have no clue as to How to proceed on that ? Excuse me if I am wrong..

Comment: @Srinivasa: Could you answer my previous comment

Comment: Not sure why all the downvotes - a lot of questions on SO have no practical application, but they're worth asking for curiosity's sake.  This is a perfectly valid question, though I think the answer is "no"

Comment: The preprocessor deals with text; templates deal with C++ types. The first happens before the second. You can't really make the second influence the first.

Comment: @BlueRaja:  Except that it doesn't make nearly as much sense as most SO questions.  Joe's comment says it all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.

1. You cannot use `#include` without the preprocessor.
2. Without preprocessor directives, including the same file twice will always result in the same sequence of tokens.

There are a couple non-portable ways to do this (both use the preprocessor), such as:

```
#pragma once
```

and

```
#import "file.h"
```

But header guards work *everywhere*, and your compiler is probably optimized to check for header guards so it won't even bother processing a duplicate `#include` directive.

Comment: +1 Agreed.  GCC is one compiler that performs the include guard check.

Answer (score 1):

That's a bit of a non-starter.  If you're `#including` files you are stuck using the preprocessor, regardless.  The closest thing you to what you ask that I'm aware of is the [`#pragma once`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragma_once) preprocessor directive, but that's not strictly portable - although it is widely available - and it of course relies on the preprocessor.